# Mysqli to Array foreach inside foreach; Inside foreach with another mysqli to array isn't reading values from the outer array properly

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, foreach

Ok here is my set up of the outer loop.

```
$sql    ="SELECT * from tblStock";
$result =mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[]=$row;
}
foreach($rows as $ad) {
```

Then keeping the connection open Inside of this loop I have a part I need to read the image urls from a database.

```
$sql        ="SELECT url from Photos where itemId ='" . $ad['ItemID'] . "';";
    echo $sql;
    $imageresult=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($imagerow=mysqli_fetch_array($imageresult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $imagerows[]=$imagerow;
    }
```

I empty the variables that would be used inside the new loop so they  are clean for every new row.

```
$image1="";
$image2="";
$image3="";
$count =0;
```

Then I use this to get out up to 3 image urls.

```
foreach($imagerows as $value) {
        switch($count) {
            case 2:
                $image3=$value['url'];
                $count =$count+1;
                break;
            case 1:
                $image2=$value['url'];
                $count =$count+1;
                break;
            case 0:
                $image1=$value['url'];
                $count =$count+1;
                break;
        } 
    }
```

These values are later written to new line in a tab file within the $rows as $ad foreach I set up at the beginning.

What I am getting is this below where the inner foreach loop for the pictures is getting stuck on the first item in the stock table and not reading from the new $ad['ItemID'] on each iteration.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your below code:

`$sql        ="SELECT url from Photos where itemId ='" . $ad['ItemID'] . "';";
    echo $sql;
    $imageresult=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($imagerow=mysqli_fetch_array($imageresult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $imagerows[]=$imagerow;
    }`

You should reset the `$imagerows[]` array just before the while loop begins. So it should look like:

`$sql        ="SELECT url from Photos where itemId ='" . $ad['ItemID'] . "';";
    echo $sql;
    $imageresult=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $imagerows = array();
    while($imagerow=mysqli_fetch_array($imageresult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $imagerows[]=$imagerow;
    }`

If you don't do that, everytime the results will keep getting added at the end of the `$imagerows`. Thus it will hold all elements of the entire result set. As a result, everytime it goes in `foreach($imagerows as $value)` loop, it will take the first 3 rows, assign their images & then not do anything (as you have restricted `$count` only for cases 0, 1 & 2.